# Format entire row with conditional_format using pandas xlswriter module

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am creating an excel report using pandas xlswriter module. Below the code-snippet for the same.

```
number_rows = len(df.index)
//df is dataframe

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Report_1.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer,"report")

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['report']

# Define range for the color formatting
color_range = "A2:F{}".format(number_rows+1)


format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

worksheet.conditional_format(color_range, {'type': 'text',
                                           'criteria' : 'containing',
                                           'value': 'SUCCESS',
                                           'format': format1})
```

I want to highlight a row ('bg_color': '#FFC7CE',                           'font_color': '#9C0006') based on a cell value(=SUCCESS). But when I use the "conditional_format" it is applying only on that particular cell. Is there any way to apply the format to the entire row if the “criteria”  matches cell value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've provided a fully reproducible example below that makes use of the `INDIRECT()` function from Excel [(Link here)](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB).  Please note that I've set the range as `$A$1:$B$6` but you can extend this to a different range if you have more columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
"Status": ['SUCCESS', 'FAIL', 'SUCCESS', 'FAIL', 'FAIL']})

number_rows = len(df.index) + 1

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Report_1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                              'font_color': '#9C0006'})

worksheet.conditional_format("$A$1:$B$%d" % (number_rows),
                             {"type": "formula",
                              "criteria": '=INDIRECT("B"&ROW())="SUCCESS"',
                              "format": format1
                             }
)

workbook.close()
```

with expected output in excel:

[image: Expected Output]