# Conditional formatting entire row pandas for excel

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, formatting, conditional-formatting

I'm fairly new to Python and I can't figure this out :
I'm trying to format a whole row based on a cell value.

I have tried this code and it does absolutely nothing to the file:

```
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Classeur.xlsx")
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Feuil1")
   writer.save()

   workbook=writer.book
   worksheet=writer.sheets['Feuil1']

   format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})


   worksheet.conditional_format('A2:C5', 
                                       {"type": "formula",
                                        "criteria": '="$B"&ROW()="FR"',
                                          "format": format1
                                       }
                            )

   workbook.close()
```

My file has three columns: `Product , Country , Sales` and I want all the rows where the country is France to be colored.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can test with the below code:

```
df= pd.DataFrame([[0,'A',1],[1,'FR',2],[2,'B',3],[3,'C',5],[4,'FR',7]])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Classeur.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Feuil1",header =False, index = False)

workbook=writer.book
worksheet=writer.sheets['Feuil1']

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE','font_color': '#9C0006'})
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:C5', {'type': 'cell','criteria': '==','value': '"FR"',"format": format1})
workbook.close()
writer.save()
```

or use :

```
df= pd.DataFrame([[0,'A',1],[1,'FR',2],[2,'B',3],[3,'C',5],[4,'FR',7]])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Classeur.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Feuil1",header =False, index = False)

workbook=writer.book
worksheet=writer.sheets['Feuil1']

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE','font_color': '#9C0006'})
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B5', {'type': 'formula','criteria': '=B2="FR"','format': format1})
workbook.close()
writer.save()
```

can remove `header =False and index = False` if you want to save column names and indexes of the data frame to excel.

If you want the **entire rows to be colored** , you can make use of the `INDIRECT()` function from excel as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527243/format-entire-row-with-conditional-format-using-pandas-xlswriter-module).

```
df= pd.DataFrame([[0,'A',1],[1,'FR',2],[2,'B',3],[3,'C',5],[4,'FR',7]])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Classeur.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Feuil1",header=False,index=False)
writer.save()

workbook=writer.book
worksheet=writer.sheets['Feuil1']

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE','font_color': '#9C0006'})
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:C5', {"type": "formula","criteria": '=INDIRECT("B"&ROW())="FR"',"format": format1})
workbook.close()
writer.save()
```

Comment: Hello this code only colors the cell, i want a mean to color the entire row, do you know how i can do that ? thank you so much